# serve 404 page of the reverse proxy site instead of NGINX's 502

Tags: nginx, next.js, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

A website is deployed to the server running on port 8000. This is a NextJS based website running in server mode via `yarn start` command.

The NextJS server is behind an NGINX server. (using NGINX as a reverse-proxy server)

I am facing issues in 404 and 5xx pages. NextJS has the built-in functionality to server 404 or 5xx page, but what happens in our case is that we get 502 page of NGINX if we hit invalid route of our website, which technically should return 404 page of NextJS.

What I want is to be able to serve 404 or 500 page of NextJS not NGINX *(we have internally verified that the website was running on port 8000 and page 404 is being served by NextJS if an invalid route is being triggered by browser)*

Here is the config block of our reverse proxy.

```
#PROXY-START/

location ^~ /
{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host localhost;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;

    error_page 404 /404;
    error_page 500 /500;

    #Persistent connection related configuration

    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    #Set Nginx Cache
    
    
    set $static_file4EjPNqQe 0;
    if ( $uri ~* "\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|woff|woff2)$" )
    {
        set $static_file4EjPNqQe 1;
        expires 12h;
        }
    if ( $static_file4EjPNqQe = 0 )
    {
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    }
}

#PROXY-END/
```

Here is the access log:

```
66.77.88.99 - - [18/May/2023:13:03:17 +0000] ＂GET /ttyyrereewww HTTP/1.1＂ 502 552 ＂-＂ ＂Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edg/113.0.1774.42＂
```

Here is the error log:

```
2023/05/18 13:03:08 [error] 3802465#0: *249566 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.77.88.99, server: pre.com, request: ＂GET /ttyyreree HTTP/1.1＂, upstream: ＂http://[::1]:8000/ttyyreree＂, host: ＂pre.com＂
2023/05/18 13:03:17 [error] 3802465#0: *249566 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 66.77.88.99, server: pre.com, request: ＂GET /ttyyrereewww HTTP/1.1＂, upstream: ＂http://localhost/ttyyrereewww＂, host: ＂pre.com＂
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but the solution to the problem was to replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`

I still want to understand why it works on `127.0.0.1` and not `localhost`